# extract multiple occurrence of a string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to fetch values:

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
```

They will always be included in the `<element>` tag

```
string sample = "This is a email template" +
                "which containe <element>Data1</element>" +
                "and also this one <element>Data2</element>" +
                "dont forget this <element>Data3</element>";

var match = Regex.Match(sample, "<element>(.*)</element>");
foreach (var item in match.Groups)
{
    var found = item;
}
```

Loop executes twice with the following set of values:

```
1 => <element>Data1</element>and also this one <element>Data2</element>dont forget this <element>Data3</element>
2 => Data1</element>and also this one <element>Data2</element>dont forget this <element>Data3
```

Any idea, what I am missing here?

Comment: `Regex.Matches(sample, "<element>(.*?)</element>").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)`

Comment: You might want to check out the `\b` syntax.